# Page displaying only 1 of 2 charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/rNBzoOm) I am trying to create 2 treemaps with D3.js but only the second treemap gets displayed. When I check the elements in the console I can see the 2 different svg's are created and written to the DOM but only the second "g" tag is populated with the SVG rect elements. There are 2 distinct div tags with distinct id's. How can I draw 2 D3.sj treemaps on side by side? Thank you.

D3.js code

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  width = 445 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 445 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz1")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// read json data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_dendrogram_full.json", function(data) {

  // Give the data to this cluster layout:
  var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value}) // Here the size of each leave is given in the 'value' field in input data

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .paddingTop(28)
    .paddingRight(7)
    .paddingInner(3)      // Padding between each rectangle
    //.paddingOuter(6)
    //.padding(20)
    (root)

  // prepare a color scale
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["source1", "source2", "source3"])
    .range([ "#402D54", "#D18975", "#8FD175"])

  // And a opacity scale
  var opacity = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 30])
    .range([.5,1])

  // use this information to add rectangles:
  svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.parent.data.name)} )
      .style("opacity", function(d){ return opacity(d.data.value)})

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name.replace('mister_','') })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("vals")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+35})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.value })
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg
    .selectAll("titles")
    .data(root.descendants().filter(function(d){return d.depth==1}))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0})
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+21})
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  function(d){ return color(d.data.name)} )

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 14)    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text("Three group sources")
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  "grey" )

})

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  width = 445 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 445 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// read json data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_dendrogram_full.json", function(data) {

  // Give the data to this cluster layout:
  var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value}) // Here the size of each leave is given in the 'value' field in input data

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .paddingTop(28)
    .paddingRight(7)
    .paddingInner(3)      // Padding between each rectangle
    //.paddingOuter(6)
    //.padding(20)
    (root)

  // prepare a color scale
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["source1", "source2", "source3"])
    .range([ "#402D54", "#D18975", "#8FD175"])

  // And a opacity scale
  var opacity = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 30])
    .range([.5,1])

  // use this information to add rectangles:
  svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.parent.data.name)} )
      .style("opacity", function(d){ return opacity(d.data.value)})

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name.replace('mister_','') })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("vals")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+35})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.value })
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg
    .selectAll("titles")
    .data(root.descendants().filter(function(d){return d.depth==1}))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0})
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+21})
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  function(d){ return color(d.data.name)} )

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 14)    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text("Three group sources")
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  "grey" )

})
```

```css
.dataviz {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="dataviz" id="my_dataviz1"></div>
<div class="dataviz" id="my_dataviz2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same name for the two SVG selections:

```
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz1")//etc...
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")//etc..
```

The solution is quite simple, give them different names:

```
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz1")//etc...
var svg2 = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")//etc...
```

Finally, considering that both drawing functions do the same, consider creating a single function to which you pass the SVG selection and the data. That way, you can substantially reduce the size of your code.

Here is your code with the changes:

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  width = 445 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 445 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz1")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// read json data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_dendrogram_full.json", function(data) {

  // Give the data to this cluster layout:
  var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value}) // Here the size of each leave is given in the 'value' field in input data

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .paddingTop(28)
    .paddingRight(7)
    .paddingInner(3)      // Padding between each rectangle
    //.paddingOuter(6)
    //.padding(20)
    (root)

  // prepare a color scale
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["source1", "source2", "source3"])
    .range([ "#402D54", "#D18975", "#8FD175"])

  // And a opacity scale
  var opacity = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 30])
    .range([.5,1])

  // use this information to add rectangles:
  svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.parent.data.name)} )
      .style("opacity", function(d){ return opacity(d.data.value)})

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name.replace('mister_','') })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("vals")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+35})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.value })
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg
    .selectAll("titles")
    .data(root.descendants().filter(function(d){return d.depth==1}))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0})
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+21})
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  function(d){ return color(d.data.name)} )

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 14)    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text("Three group sources")
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  "grey" )

})

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  width = 445 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 445 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg2 = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// read json data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_dendrogram_full.json", function(data) {

  // Give the data to this cluster layout:
  var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value}) // Here the size of each leave is given in the 'value' field in input data

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .paddingTop(28)
    .paddingRight(7)
    .paddingInner(3)      // Padding between each rectangle
    //.paddingOuter(6)
    //.padding(20)
    (root)

  // prepare a color scale
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["source1", "source2", "source3"])
    .range([ "#402D54", "#D18975", "#8FD175"])

  // And a opacity scale
  var opacity = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 30])
    .range([.5,1])

  // use this information to add rectangles:
  svg2
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.parent.data.name)} )
      .style("opacity", function(d){ return opacity(d.data.value)})

  // and to add the text labels
  svg2
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name.replace('mister_','') })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // and to add the text labels
  svg2
    .selectAll("vals")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+35})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.value })
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "white")

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg2
    .selectAll("titles")
    .data(root.descendants().filter(function(d){return d.depth==1}))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0})
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+21})
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  function(d){ return color(d.data.name)} )

  // Add title for the 3 groups
  svg2
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 14)    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text("Three group sources")
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill",  "grey" )

})
```

```css
.dataviz {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="dataviz" id="my_dataviz1"></div>
<div class="dataviz" id="my_dataviz2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.